# Beautify comentário inline

Tags: css, extensão

Estou utilizando a extensão Beautify no VSCode para organizar melhor meu código, porem encontrei um problema e não achei a solução, ele joga sempre o comentário para próxima linha.
Como corrigir isso?

```css
/*Antes:*/
margin: 0; /* retira a margem e o espaço entre os elementos */

/*Depois:*/
margin: 0;
/* retira a margem e o espaço entre os elementos */
```

Comment: Não usar isso? Tem alguma configuração nele?

Comment: Então, Maniero, eu gosto desta extensão para identar e organizar bem o meu código, porem esse é o único problema dela e não consigo corrigir. Sim, tem configuração.

Comment: Talvez isso seja alguma config do próprio VSCode e não do Beautify depois da uma pesquisada...

Comment: Isso é uma configuração do Beautify mesmo, estava olhando aqui no GIT da extensão. Ele vai ter que buscar uma forma alternativa para esse comportamento funcionar. Quem sabe buscando uma outra extensão.

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia Hardel,

Vou detalhar um pouco sobre este problema, e o que eu pesquisei. As versões  recentes do Beautify não vão permitir o comentário na mesma linha no seu CSS(Não sei em outras). Utilizei "[esta](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify)" versão.

> Observei que a extensão do beautify possui uma configuração que pode ser configuradas para quebra de linhas como a `"html.format.endWithNewline": false` no entanto para o comentário que você precisa dentro do CSS, não irá funcionar porque esta extensão foi feita para funcionar desta forma(Ou seja, com essa quebra de linha).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] (Não adianta configurar conforme a imagem)

PS: A cerca de 9 meses esse complemento sofreu a alteração abaixo, é possivel que uma versão antiga possa funcionar do jeito que você espera:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

PS: De toda forma essa é uma reclamação bem comum nos forums do Beautify. Então eu partiria para busca de uma outra extensão se de fato for necessário estes comentários no teu código.

Espero ter ajudado. Abraços!

Comment: Pessoal, por gentileza, peço para apontar o comentário referente a negativação. Pois se não tiver ajudado removo esta consulta que fiz no GIT do Beutify.

Comment: Nem foi eu que te negativei, mas vc testou o seu código? Cade o link da extensão no Market Place do VS Code? Como coloca essa config para funcionar na extensão dentro do VS Code pra gente testar?

Comment: Geremias, bom dia! Tudo bem. Não fiz o teste em meu código, não uso o Beautify, mas ele é parecido com outros complementos que uso. 
Para fazer um ajuste nas configurações podes seguir essa documentação:  [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify) , tem um monte de coisas legais que podes definir nas configurações desse complemento. :)

Comment: Sem ofenças, mas deve ser por isso que te negativaram... se vc testar isso que vc postou vai ver que não funciona... http://prntscr.com/o6fu1a

Comment: Olha ai quebrando linha no comentário mesmo com a config, aqui pelo menos não funciona https://imgur.com/dcrIEtG

Comment: Obrigado hugocsl pelo feedback. Vou tentar alguma solução alternativa e posto jaja por aqui editando o tópico.

Comment: Hugo de fato não funciona, rodei todas as configurações da extensão e nada. Mas avaliei o código no git e de fato esse comportamento foi implementado de propósito. 
PS: Agradeço pelos comentários aqui!  Abraços